# Rotate proxy on each request python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, proxy, python-requests, rotation

I have a script that fills and submits on form using python requests but it gets blocked every couple requests so I have a list of proxies that I want to use for each request. Is there any way to do that? Any help is appreciated thank you in advance!

```
proxy_list = ['sampleproxy']


s = requests.post("https://a.klaviyo.com/ajax/subscriptions/subscribe", data=payload)
    
for mail in mails:
    payload['$email'] = mail
    print("Entering " + mail)
    s
    if s.text == '{"errors": [], "data": {"is_subscribed": true}, "success": true}':
        successful_entries.append(mail)
        print("Entered " + mail)
    elif s.text == '{"errors": ["List does not exist."], "data": {}, "success": false}':
        unsuccessful_entries.append(mail)
        print("Failed to Enter " + mail)

print(successful_entries)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
for mail,proxy in zip(mails,proxy_list):
```

But it depends on how you want to use your porxies,

- do you want to use a different one everytime?
- how long is your proxy list?
- is the length of `mails` and `proxy_list the same`?

Comment: yea I want to use a diff one every time, proxy list is as long as mails.

Comment: Then the answer I provided is fine, zip iterates through two list at the same time